# Transition doesn't apply on element

Tags: javascript, css, css-transitions

I want to have a div that is on the center of the page (I use 300px now) and when some seconds pass, I want to make visible a second div and make them both to be at the center with 50px difference, this is what I've done now, my first problem is why the opacity change of the second div doesn't apply?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Whatever</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <style type="text/css">
        #main {
            position: absolute;
            top: 200px;
            left: 300px;
        }

        div.c {
            width: 200px;
            height: 200px;
            float:left;
            position:relative;
            left:200px;
            -webkit-transition:left 2s;
        }

        #left {
            background-color: palevioletred;
        }

        #right {
            -webkit-transition:opacity 2s;
            background-color: ThreeDDarkShadow;
            opacity:0;
        }
    </style>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.onload = function () {
            setTimeout("myfunc()", 3000);
        }

        function myfunc() {
            var stupido = document.getElementsByClassName("c");
            for (var i in stupido) {
                stupido[i].style.left = 0;
            }
            document.getElementById("right").style.opacity = 1;
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="main">
        <div id="left" class="c">x</div>
        <div id="right" class="c">x</div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you should use jQuery, it would make what you're doing easier, but I'm not sure what's wrong with your code

Comment: i don't like personally jquery, i want to write clear javascript.

Comment: jquery provides function like animate and switchClass its a smooth solution. in my opinion pure js is not the best as you will have to make a timeout function or something to get your animation running...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As `stupido` is an `HTMLCollection` instead of an array, its `length` property got looped through. `stupido[i].style === undefined`, generates error, script crashes.

Change `for(var i in stupido)` to `for(i=0; i<stupido.length; i++)`
Also, [don't use string in setTimeout when possible](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setTimeout)

[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WQtPc/3/)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/HwHdc/ ...I want the gray box to do the same thing as it does now on this fiddle, but i want it to change opacity from 0 to 1 throught that time

Comment: Like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/WQtPc/5/)? The problem was `transition` doesn't add up but overwrite instead. A word of note: I used to dislike jQuery too but I found out it was too powerful to ignore: [same thing using jquery](http://jsfiddle.net/WQtPc/6/)